# How to add pauses to my PHP script?

Tags: php, email

I have mail send script (using PHP). This script can send too much emails .... Now I need a limit for this script. The limit: When we want to send 1000 emails, the script after send 100 emails sleep for 60 (seconds). This pseudo-code explains:

```
send 100 mails ....
send ok.
sleep 60s.(stop sending for 60s)
send other 100 mails (100-200)...
send ok.
sleep 60s. (stop sending for 60s)
send other 100 mails (200-300)...
```

There are two limit on this script now:

```
$max_chars = 20000;
$max_sends = 100000;
```

But I need two more limits:

```
$sleep_time = 60s;
$sleep_after_send = 100;
```

Could you please help me put this two new limits on this script for me and write the classes?

Comment: Um...no? We aren't here to do things for you. We are here to help with programming problems. If you want someone to do this for you, I suggest you find a programmer and pay them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use php sleep function

```
for($i = 1 ;$i <= $max_sends ; $i++)
{
    // send email here and check status
    if($i % 100 == 0)
        sleep(60);  
}
```

Source for sleep function http://php.net/sleep

Comment: Minor point: you can swap `100` for the `$sleep_after_send` value, and ditto `60` for `$sleep_time`.